# IIS Shadowcopy not copying xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Visual Studio 2015, x64 machine, using local IIS to host a MVC 5 application.

I have an XML file that is required for my application (log4net config file). I've  have the file set to 'content' and 'always copy to output directory'. This file copies to the bin\debug directory fine.

Unfortunately, when a browser makes any request, I get:

Could not find file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\solvernode\e0f7ede5\23a22c5c\assembly\dl3\89db89ce\7f06f1f4_272ed101\ISAMSLog4Net.xml`

Investigating that directory, I find nothing but a dependent dll.

I have:
 - Deleted asp.net temp directory files.
 - Removed all bin/obj folders
 - Restarted everything in sight, from the app pool up to IIS.
 - Rebooted
 - Rebuild the site from scratch using  a new MVC 5 templated project.

My box has .net 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6 on it, installed in that order.

Sure could use some help on this one.   Full stack trace below:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\solvernode\e0f7ede5\23a22c5c\assembly\dl3\89db89ce\7f06f1f4_272ed101\ISAMSLog4Net.xml'.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +1346
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +886
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +164
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) +177
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path) +53
SolverSupport.Logging.GetLogFileNameFromLog4NetConfig(String log4NetConfigPath) in C:\Repos\ISAMS\SolverSupport\Logging.cs:53
SolverSupport.Logging.WireUpLogging() in C:\Repos\ISAMS\SolverSupport\Logging.cs:16
StressCheckSolver.Solver.Init() in C:\Repos\ISAMS\StressCheckSolver\Solver.cs:20
I2ES.SolverNode.SolverLauncher.SolverLauncher.LaunchStressCheckSolver(Int32 jobId, Action`2 completedCallback) in C:\repos\ISAMS\I2ES\SolverNode\SolverLauncher\SolverLauncher.cs:41
I2ES.SolverNode.Controllers.SolverController.Submit(Int32 id) in C:\repos\ISAMS\I2ES\SolverNode\Controllers\SolverController.cs:15
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +141
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: This turned out to be **PEBKAC** (problem exists between keyboard and chair.)  A child library was erroneously calling Log4Net directly rather than through the framework.  It was looking for an xml file IIS had never been told to copy.

Answer (score 0):

How are you attempting to load the XML file from within the SolverSupport.Logging.GetLogFileNameFromLog4NetConfig method?  It looks like you are referencing the folder location incorrectly.